# Adjust space between chapter number and caption in TOC

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft

I have document like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}} 
\begin{document}
\chapter{Some title}
\chapter{Some other title}
\chapter{One more title}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

It produces table of contents like:
[image: what I have]

What i need is no space between chapter number ant its caption, like:
[image: what I need]

[tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) allows to use `\cftchapnumwidth` command , but it is "static", I want chapnumwidth to be adjusted to each number.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your request would generate ToCs being difficult to read.

Answer (score 2):

Even [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) still uses the traditional setting of the ToC entry numbers inside a box (of width `\cftZnumwidth`, where `Z` is the sectional unit). But, we can patch `\l@chapter` to momentarily adjust `\numberline` - the macro causing the problems. The patching is supplied by [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox).

Below I've done so, even though the readability of the ToC now completely suffers from it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}% <cmd>
  {\leavevmode}% <search>
  {\leavevmode%
   \renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{\hbox{\@cftbsnum ##1\@cftasnum}\@cftasnumb}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}} 
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Some title}
\section{A section}

\chapter{Some other title}

\chapter{One more title}

\end{document}
```

For a fixed space after the chapter numeral, adjust `\cftchappresnum` to something like `~`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{book}

\def\numberline#1{#1}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}} 
\begin{document}
\chapter{Some title}
\chapter{Some other title}
\chapter{One more title}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you have sections with the default TOC entry then use:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \begingroup
      \def\numberline##1{##1}
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}} 
\begin{document}
\chapter{Some title}
\section{foo}
\chapter{Some other title}
\chapter{One more title}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```